# I am getting the following error when i try to update the currency table using batch apex

Tags: apex

Error:
(CALLOUT_RESPONSE,System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401])

Code:

```
global class  updateCurrencyBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts {
    String batchQuery='';
    List<CurrencyType> localscope = new List<CurrencyType>();
    List<Exchange_Rate__c> ctlist = new List<Exchange_Rate__c>();
    Map<String,Double> updateRateMap = new Map<String,Double>();
    global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        system.debug('***Start Method');                    
        batchQuery = 'Select  id,IsoCode From CurrencyType where isActive=true';              
        return Database.getQueryLocator(batchQuery);    
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<CurrencyType> Scope) {
        localscope=Scope;
        ctlist =[SELECT  currency_code__c,rate__c,Archived__c FROM Exchange_Rate__c WHERE Archived__c=false];
        for(Exchange_Rate__c et : ctlist){
            updateRateMap.put(et.currency_code__c,Double.ValueOf(et.rate__c));
        }
        for(CurrencyType ct : localScope){                          
            String id=ct.id;                          
            String str = String.valueOf(ct.IsoCode);
            Double val = Double.valueOf(updateRateMap.get(ct.IsoCode));  
            system.debug('***Isocode:'+str);                       
            system.debug('***rate:'+val);
            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/CurrencyType/'+id+'?_HttpMethod=PATCH');
            Map<String,double> mapstrBydouble=new Map<String,double>();
            mapstrBydouble.put('ConversionRate',val);
            String body=JSON.serialize(mapstrBydouble);
            system.debug('body'+JSON.serialize(mapstrBydouble));
            req.setBody(body);  
            req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setMethod('POST');
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {       
    }  
}
```

Comment: @Mohith Kumar
Could you please help me.

Comment: Any reason you aren't just updating the CurrencyType directly in Apex?  Not sure I understand why you're doing a callout ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per part of FrankZ's answer, the [UserInfo.getSessionId](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_UserInfo_getSessionId.htm) method does not work in Batch.

> For Apex code that is executed asynchronously, such as @future methods, Batch Apex jobs, or scheduled Apex jobs, getSessionId returns null.

Pass in the Session ID to the batch job from the interactive context your starting the job from...

```
Databae.executeBatch(new updateCurrencyBatch(UserInfo.getSessionId()));

public class updateCurrencyBatch ...
{
    private final String sessionId;

    public updateCurrencyBatch(String sessionId)
    {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }

    ...

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<CurrencyType> Scope) 
    {
       ...
       req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + sessionId);
       ...
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** You don't need to define your class and methods as 'global', doing so, if your packaging your code will give rise to constraints around deleting and modifying the class. If your not packaging your code (e.g. its just production code), its not a huge issue, but does no harm to make them 'public' just in case.

Finally, note that the Session ID does not last forever, so if there is some delays in starting the job and the user signs out, it may become invalid. So ensure you have some adequate error handle and recovery process for the user to follow. If you wanted to go further you can perform a login from Apex, though this presents other challenges.

Answer (score 1):

This is a batch Apex job. I am pretty sure that `UserInfo.getSessionId()` is null. 
Also, I am wondering the same as @Ralph, why do you want to update CurrencyType through the REST API?

Comment: Because DML Operations are not allowed on Currency Type in salesforce
@FrankZ

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but it may save you some time.

Using DML Statements in APEX to directly update any Salesforce table is A LOT easier than calling the REST API (which is pretty sweet, but is on the whole more "advanced" than APEX).

For example instead of that big for loop, you could just do have a nice one line dml statement like `update localScope;`

A great place to learn more about this would be the [Working with Data in APEX](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_data_intro.htm) section of the APEX API Docs.  **Note**: after following that link click the "Open with Navigation" link at the top of the page.

Comment: We cannot use DML statements directly on Currency Table in salesforce. So thats why going through rest api.
@Ralph

Comment: Are you sure that's the case?  Perhaps you're having a permissions error somewhere?  Unfortunately I don't have an org with CurrencyType available to test, but the [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/Content/sforce_api_objects_currencytype.htm) state that the object is updateable.  Also wasn't aware of situations where the API could update objects that APEX couldn't.